# LatLang through Json NullPointer

Tags: android, json, google-maps

i received LatLang through Json but now i want to show then on Maps in Postexecute method this is my code

```
 ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
        Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
        String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS, ServiceHandler.GET);
        // print the json response in the log
        Log.d("Get match fixture resps", "> " + json);
        if (json != null) {
            try {
                Log.d("try", "in the try");
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                int len = matchFixture.length();
                Log.d("len", "get array length");
                for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double matchId = Double.parseDouble(c.getString(TAG_MATCHID));
                    Log.d("matchId", String.valueOf(matchId));
                    Double teamA = Double.valueOf(c.getString(TAG_TEAMA));
                    Log.d("teamA", String.valueOf(teamA));

                    //  hashmap for single match
                    HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, String.valueOf(matchId));
                    matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMA, String.valueOf(teamA));

                    matchFixtureList.add(new LatLng(matchId, teamA));


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for (LatLng point:matchFixtureList){
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("chexk"));
        }

        // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pakistan).title("Marker in pakistn"));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
        }
```

so how can i show markers on the map i receive all lat and lang in log but its show nullpointer in logcat`dfdfd`

Comment: are you getting error if latitude longitude provided are hardcoded?? or it is displaying properly?

Comment: If your `matchFixtureList` is a global variable, I don't think that you need to change anything. But it would be a better practice to follow @ccsnoopy's answer.

Comment: sir i just want want to show markers according to the LatLang i recieved through JSON

Comment: I think that you're looking for something like this http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returned `null` in your (what I assume is) `doInBackground()` method.

Try changing your `doInBackground` to something like:

```
@Override
protected List<LatLng> doInBackground(Someparam... params){
    List<LatLng> matchFixtureList = new ArrayList<>();
    //rest of your code

    return matchFixtureList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<LatLng> result){
    for (LatLng point: result){//access your result from doInBackground
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("chexk"));
    }
   //the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: sir now app does't crash but not showing the markers

Comment: I don't know how your mMap works, but with the information provided currently, I can't do much unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the steps from the tutorial. Cross check if you have followed everything.
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-marker-at-user-input-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Make more stress on Keystore part. Is it same you using or other one